# htaccess Rewrite URL Without .php Extension To File

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I got a website that using osCommerce which all the page can be access directly with `http://www.example.com/pagename.php`, but now I would like to tweak the htaccess file so that it can supports `http://www.example.com/username` and then redirecting to `http://www.example.com/account.php?id=username`, while other pages still can be access using the same old way.

It means that if the htaccess detect that the URL didn't have any extension, then it will be redirecting to `http://www.example.com/account.php?id=username`.

Thank you!

Comment: [Seach Engine Friendly URL](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/2796) ? [Ultimate SEO URLs](http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/2823) ? [SEO, Meta Tags, SEF Urls and osCommerce](http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/254741-seo-meta-tags-sef-urls-and-oscommerce/) ?

Comment: Sorry I doesn't want to rewrite my entire site. Thanks for your reply anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need one rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ /account.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works! Never thought that it was so simple, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this code to remove php extension from URL:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet

# This will redirect you from http://www.example.com/username.php to 
# http://www.example.com/username externally                                                          
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# This will redirect you from http://www.example.com/username to 
# http://www.example.com/username internally   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: This will be rewriting the entire site already right? I want to remain the .php for all the pages, just add one more rewrite so that if there is no extension in the URL it will rewrite automatically.