# MultiViews is *too* tolerant of bad URLs

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, multiview, multiviews

When I enable MultiViews, if I visit bad URLs, the my page (index.php) is still reached, when I want the user to get a 404 error instead. I'm trying to figure out how to fix this without creating rules in my `.htaccess`.

For example, "www.mydomain.com/**index**/blah/blah", visits **index.php**, but I want it to fail due to the extraneous trailing garbage URL components. Similarly for "/**contact**/blah/awuihda/hiu", which shows the content of **contact.php**,  should give a 404 error, because "/blah/awuihda/hiu" doesn't exist.

If I disable MultiViews it works fine, but then I can't abbreviate the URL as much as I want to (for example, can't type "/contact" to bring up "contact.php").

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the following so the `.php` extension is not required, which is the usual approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Remove .php if it's present with a 301 redirect
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]
# If a request doesn't exist as a directory, file or symlink
# and it does exist with .php appended, rewrite to that
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L]
```

I know it's adding a rule to `.htaccess` but it's a one off that works for everything and also means you're not hitting potential duplicate content allowing the same thing to be served with or without `.php` (or indeed with anything at all trailing after it as in your examples). Hope it's useful.

It could go in main server config but would need altering.

Comment: How would i need to change this to add it into my server configuration?

Comment: With this in my server configuration it redirects my **/news** site so **/games/csgo/news**, which returns a 404.

Comment: I updated it to work in the server configuration instead of .htaccess

Comment: Let me know if you still get a problem with your news site, not sure exactly what you're saying it was doing, redirecting /news to /games/csgo/news ?

Comment: Sorry one more thing, in your server config, it needs to go within the <Directory> block for your document root or the file tests won't work.

Comment: Ignore that last comment. Was a bug from Chrome i think. Thanks but now i get the message **The page isn't redirecting properly**. Here is a Link to my config [link](http://pastebin.com/Wa50PmjN) EDIT: It is unter my Directory block.

Comment: I added the `[L]` flag to the bottom rule which should fix that. If not, change it to `[END]`. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thank you very much but i think i found a way to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me.

```
Options -Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840581/htaccess-rewrite-url-without-php-extension-to-file)